# Updating array of objects in redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

the following is my Component that triggers the action and monitors for changes:

```
import { Box, Button, Stack, TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import {
  handleDirectorAdd,
  handleDirectorInfoFormChange,
  handleDirectorRemove,
} from "../../../../redux/slices/directorInfo";

const DirectorsInformation = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const directorsInfo = useSelector((state) => state.directorInfo);

  const handleChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    if (name && value) {
      dispatch(handleDirectorInfoFormChange({ name, value, index }));
    }
  };

  const handleAdd = () => {
    dispatch(handleDirectorAdd());
  };

  const handleRemove = (e, index) => {
    dispatch(handleDirectorRemove({ index }));
  };

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      noValidate
      style={{
        padding: "1rem",
        backgroundColor: "white",
        border: "1px solid darkgrey",
        textAlign: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Typography variant="body1">
        <strong>Director&apos;s Information</strong>
      </Typography>
      <hr />
      {directorsInfo?.map((directorInfo, index) => (
        <div key={uuidv4()}>
          <Stack
            spacing={1}
            alignItems="center"
            style={{
              padding: "1rem",
              backgroundColor: "rgb(227, 227, 227)",
            }}
          >
            <Typography variant="body1">Director&apos;s Information</Typography>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="error"
              sx={{ textTransform: "none" }}
              onClick={(e) => handleRemove(e, index)}
            >
              Remove
            </Button>
            <Typography variant="body1">
              <strong>Full Name</strong>
            </Typography>
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              size="small"
              label="Full Name"
              name="name"
              value={directorInfo.name}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, index)}
              sx={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
            />
            <Typography variant="body1">
              <strong>Official Email</strong>
            </Typography>
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              size="small"
              label="Official Email"
              name="email"
              type="email"
              value={directorInfo.email}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, index)}
              sx={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
            />
            <Typography variant="body1">
              <strong>Contact Number</strong>
            </Typography>
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              size="small"
              label="Contact Number"
              name="contactNumber"
              value={directorInfo.contactNumber}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, index)}
              sx={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
            />
            <Typography variant="body1">
              <strong>Title</strong>
            </Typography>
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              size="small"
              label="Tile"
              name="title"
              type="string"
              value={directorInfo.title}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, index)}
              sx={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
            />
          </Stack>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="success"
            sx={{ textTransform: "none", margin: "2rem 0" }}
            onClick={handleAdd}
          >
            Add Directors Information
          </Button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </form>
  );
};

export default DirectorsInformation;
```

Now the reducer and action are as follows:

```
import { createSlice, current } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const initialValues = {
  name: "",
  email: "",
  contactNumber: "",
  username: "",
  title: "",
};
const initialState = [initialValues];

const directorInfo = createSlice({
  name: "directorInfo",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    handleDirectorAdd(state, action) {
      return [...state, initialValues];
    },
    handleDirectorRemove(state, action) {
      return state.filter((_, index) => index !== action.payload.index);
    },
    handleDirectorInfoFormChange(state, action) {
      const { index, name, value } = action.payload;
      return state.map((director, idx) => {
          if (idx === index) {
          return {
            ...director,
            [name]: value,
          };
        } else {
          return director;
        }
      });
    },
  },
});

export const {
  handleDirectorAdd,
  handleDirectorRemove,
  handleDirectorInfoFormChange,
} = directorInfo.actions;

export default directorInfo.reducer;
```

The problem I am facing is that when I change value in the input field of the form, the value gets updated but it causes re-render(I'm assuming that since the focus towards the input field is removed). I am trying to update the state inside the redux store when the value of any director is changed or when they are added and removed. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you

I tried to mutate the state. The state is being mutated correctly but it is causing re-render, which I don't want. I've tried filter function instead of map but still was not able to achieve the desired result. I want that the user can write inside the input box smoothly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

When you update the state a rerender will be the intended result. The root issue you have though is cause by using a random React key each render cycle on the mapped `directorsInfo` state array.

```js
{directorsInfo?.map((directorInfo, index) => (
  <div key={uuidv4()}> // <-- Random React key == bad
    ...
  </div>
))}
```

Each time `DirectorsInformation` rerenders, each and every mapped `directorsInfo` array element's JSX uses a ***different*** React key (*than from the previous render cycle*) and so React treats this JSX as being new and unmounts the old JSX and mounts the new JSX *even though* it is the same UI.

## Solution

Pretty much don't ever use random React keys. Ideally you want to use key values that are intrinsically related to the data you are rendering, like any GUID or unique property of the data that exists with the data for the life of the data.

In this case I suggest adding an `id` property to your state. You can continue using the `uuid` package if you like, but Redux-Toolkit also re-exports [`nanoid`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/other-exports#nanoid) for use cases like this.

Example:

```js
import { createSlice, nanoid } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialValues = {
  name: "",
  email: "",
  contactNumber: "",
  username: "",
  title: "",
};

const initialState = [{
  ...initialValues,
  id: nanoid(), // <-- generate id when creating object
}];

const directorInfo = createSlice({
  name: "directorInfo",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    handleDirectorAdd(state, action) {
      state.push({
        ...initialValues,
        id: nanoid(), // <-- generate id when creating object
      });
    },
    handleDirectorRemove(state, action) {
      return state.filter((director) => director.id !== action.payload.id);
    },
    handleDirectorInfoFormChange(state, action) {
      const { id, name, value } = action.payload;

      return state.map((director) => director.id === id
        ? { ...director, [name]: value }
        : director);
    },
  },
});
```

```
const DirectorsInformation = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const directorsInfo = useSelector((state) => state.directorInfo);

  const handleChange = (e, id) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    if (name && value) {
      dispatch(handleDirectorInfoFormChange({ name, value, id }));
    }
  };

  const handleAdd = () => {
    dispatch(handleDirectorAdd());
  };

  const handleRemove = (e, id) => {
    dispatch(handleDirectorRemove({ id }));
  };

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      noValidate
      style={{
        padding: "1rem",
        backgroundColor: "white",
        border: "1px solid darkgrey",
        textAlign: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Typography variant="body1">
        <strong>Director&apos;s Information</strong>
      </Typography>
      <hr />
      {directorsInfo?.map((director) => (
        <div key={director.id}> // <-- use id property
          <Stack
            spacing={1}
            alignItems="center"
            style={{
              padding: "1rem",
              backgroundColor: "rgb(227, 227, 227)",
            }}
          >
            <Typography variant="body1">Director&apos;s Information</Typography>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="error"
              sx={{ textTransform: "none" }}
              onClick={(e) => handleRemove(e, director.id)} // <-- pass id property
            >
              Remove
            </Button>
            <Typography variant="body1">
              <strong>Full Name</strong>
            </Typography>
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              size="small"
              label="Full Name"
              name="name"
              value={director.name}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, director.id)} // <-- pass id property
              sx={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
            />
            <Typography variant="body1">
              <strong>Official Email</strong>
            </Typography>
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              size="small"
              label="Official Email"
              name="email"
              type="email"
              value={director.email}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, director.id)} // <-- pass id property
              sx={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
            />
            <Typography variant="body1">
              <strong>Contact Number</strong>
            </Typography>
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              size="small"
              label="Contact Number"
              name="contactNumber"
              value={director.contactNumber}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, director.id)} // <-- pass id property
              sx={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
            />
            <Typography variant="body1">
              <strong>Title</strong>
            </Typography>
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              size="small"
              label="Tile"
              name="title"
              type="string"
              value={director.title}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, director.id)} // <-- pass id property
              sx={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
            />
          </Stack>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="success"
            sx={{ textTransform: "none", margin: "2rem 0" }}
            onClick={handleAdd}
          >
            Add Directors Information
          </Button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </form>
  );
};
```